# Why was this question migrated to Code Review?

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025554/is-there-any-way-to-refacter-the-code-how-can-i-write-it-better?noredirect=1) was migrated to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236539/is-there-any-way-to-refacter-the-code-how-can-i-write-it-better).

However, it has multiple issues that disqualify it as a candidate for migration:

1. It is off-topic on the target site. Close reason: *Code Review requires [concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652) for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.* This code is not a function nor does it have any explanation.
2. The question is low quality. It is unclear what the question is about and what it is asking for. It is no better on Code Review.
3. See also [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users), in particular ***Questions with insufficient context***: *A question that does not describe properly what the code does, while not immediately* off-topic, *is very likely to collect down-votes. To help reviewers give you better answers, Code Review questions should include a description of what the code does. The more you tell us about what your code does and the purpose of it, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.*

Why was it migrated?

Comment: I fully agree. It's a terrible question for both this site and the Code Review site.

Comment: I agree, I already voted to close it on code review.

Comment: This is a site process question: is the intent of this post to enumerate the reasons for not migrating a Q - or to actually understand why it was migrated.  Since the migrator is known perhaps they should be involved in some way.  Seems the title of this post should be "This question should not have been migrated for the following reasons.".  Is there any way to reject a migration "with reason"?  When a Q is migrated - a reason is supplied on the "send" side - but in this case peer review on the receive side did not agree - so what opportunity is there for resolution.

Comment: @Andy Both: I wanted to let the person that migrated it know that they shouldn't have migrated it and ask what their reasoning was. A rejection is caused by a moderator or by a closure -- both of which have not happened yet.

Comment: Here is a relevant link to the Code Review meta site: [What questions are suitable for migration to Code Review, and how does the process work?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1687/5383).

Comment: I do wonder why 2 people disagreed with / down-voted this post -- what their arguments are for allowing migration of low-quality questions to another site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels or do the votes actually mean "I disagree with the migration"? Or maybe "I disagree with you asking about migrations"? I'm not sure, really. Given that the question asks "why" I'm not sure it's clear that an upvote means "Yes, it shouldn't have" or "No, it should have". Same goes for downvotes. I personally upvoted but for neither of these reasons but because I think it's a useful question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the link.  Boy, quite a bit of overhead here - since the post clearly violated step 2 ("working code" - i.e. it had syntax errors), the incorrectly migrated code must then get reviewed -> closed -> and -> " the entire process of the migration is reversed" (i.e. post returns to originating site) (assuming not 'duplicate' and other exceptions).  Seems like the last step should be exceptional - and normal process should be post ends up in a "rejected" bucket (still accessible by poster) left to decay.  Anyways - thanks for the info.

Comment: You have understood (1) incorrectly. It's purely about the code, and the code is there. (2) and (3) are the same thing - don't migrate low quality posts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because I am a numpty and didn’t look closely enough. Sorry.

It was flagged asking for a migration and I saw a broad request asking for someone’s code to be improved. I scanned for comments pointing out that the code didn’t work, didn’t find any, and migrated it. That was dumb of me, I should’ve looked closer, as there actually was a comment there pointing out compilation issues.

I don’t know why I didn’t pay more attention. I normally do look for a description of what the code is supposed to achieve. I was tired yesterday (sleep deprived, happens sometimes), I have no other excuse.

Comment: So you *are* human after all! You almost had us fooled :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen *or* my programming includes making occasional mistakes so as to dissuade suspicions. ;-)

Comment: Awh, shucks.... So you're basically just a [drum machine](https://books.google.no/books?id=HjFXLtvrqh4C&pg=PT140&lpg=PT140&dq=%22drum+machine%22+timing+errors+to+sound+more+realistic&source=bl&ots=piQrGig-Mt&sig=ACfU3U2sZYaVMQbnyZmFL2914BycS-dqHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_9uZiLXnAhVHwqYKHdJlAykQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22drum%20machine%22%20timing%20errors%20to%20sound%20more%20realistic&f=false) evolved.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: sounds about right. Although I don't think [my various](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Future_Magazine_4#Music) [attempts at](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Future_Magazine_5#Music)  [programming music](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Future_Magazine_6#Music) [in the 1990s](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Future_Magazine_7#Music) show much familiarity with quantization yet..

Comment: That's fine. People make mistaked.